# What causes the this.myFunction is not a function error in this JavaScript class?

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I am working at displaying a JSON in the form of an HTML table using plain (vanilla) JavaScript.

I am appending rows created dynamically from the JSON to the table's body:

```js
class CountriesList {
  constructor() {
    this.apiURL =
      "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Goles/3196253/raw/9ca4e7e62ea5ad935bb3580dc0a07d9df033b451/CountryCodes.json";
    this.countries = [];
    this.searchBox = document.querySelector("#searchBox");
    this.stringToMatch = "";
    this.tableRows = "";
  }

  // Render rows
  renderRows = (arr, container) => {
    let el = document.querySelector(container);
    el.innerHTML = "";
    el.innerHTML += arr
      .map(function(item) {
        return `<tr>
              <td>${item.name}</td>
              <td class="text-right">${item.code}</td>
              <td class="text-right">
                <button data-code="${item.code}" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="this.deleteRow()">
                  <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
              </td>
           </tr>`;
      })
      .join("");
  };

  // Get Items
  getFilteredCountries = async() => {
    const response = await fetch(this.apiURL);
    this.countries = await response.json();
    // If there is a search string, filter results
    this.stringToMatch = this.searchBox.value;
    if (this.stringToMatch.length > 0) {
      this.countries = this.countries.filter((country) => {
        return (
          country.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.stringToMatch.toLowerCase()) ||
          country.code.includes(this.stringToMatch.toUpperCase())
        );
      });
      this.renderRows(this.countries, "#countries_table tbody");
    }
  };

  deleteRow() {
    let deleteBtns = document.querySelectorAll("#countries_table tr button");
    console.log(event.target.dataset.code);
    this.countries = this.countries.filter(() => item.code != event.target.dataset.code);
    this.renderRows(this.countries, "#countries_table tbody");
  };

  hideLoader = async() => {
    let loader = document.querySelector(".loader");
    const action = this.countries.length > 0 ? "add" : "remove";
    loader.classList[action]("d-none");
  };

  init = async() => {
    await this.getFilteredCountries();
    await this.hideLoader();
    this.searchBox.addEventListener("keyup", this.getFilteredCountries);
    this.renderRows(this.countries, "#countries_table tbody");
  };
}

const countriesList = new CountriesList();
countriesList.init();
```

```css
.loader {
  border: 4px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-top: 4px solid #3498db;
  opacity: .85;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="card bg-light shadow-sm my-2">
    <div class="card-header px-3 d-flex">
      <h6 class="text-dark m-0 align-self-center">Countries of the World</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body bg-white position-relative p-0">
      <div class="search mx-2">
        <input class="my-2 form-control" id="searchBox" type="text" placeholder="Search..." value="">
      </div>
      <table class="table mb-0" id="countries_table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th class="text-right">Code</th>
            <th class="text-right">Delete</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div class="loader"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### The problem

In the template literal of the renderRows method, I have added a **delete button**:

```
<button data-code="${item.code}" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="this.deleteRow()">
   <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
```

When I click a delete button, I get this error in the browser:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.deleteRow is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `this` in a html property is NOT the instance of an object

Comment: you cannot reference this directly in HTML remove the this keyword and it should work fine

Comment: @AkshayBhat It is not in HTML, it is in the script, where every method id called with `this`.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir you pass string while creating HTML, not the function itself, so after click, `this` is equal to `window` and not CountryList.

Comment: @FilipKováč I deleted the `this` keyword and it still does not work. :(

Comment: @RazvanZamfir of course, the `deleteRow()` doesnt exist on global `window`. Instead use global event handler where you pass some identifier and delete it from instance of CountriesList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second try. Everything should work now. I played around with it a bit trying different approaches just because I wanted to understand why certain solutions weren't working as I expected.

This works fine as far as I can tell, though some times a country won't be deleted and will output null in the console instead of the country code, but inspecting the button shows everything it in place and then the button will randomly just work and delete the country...you might need to look into that.

Hopefully this helps. I've added a couple of comments where the new code is; feel free to ask me any questions regarding the changes (though I might not know any more than you do tbh :p )

```js
class CountriesList {
  constructor() {
    this.apiURL =
      "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Goles/3196253/raw/9ca4e7e62ea5ad935bb3580dc0a07d9df033b451/CountryCodes.json";
    this.countries = [];
    this.searchBox = document.querySelector("#searchBox");
    this.stringToMatch = "";
    this.tableRows = "";
  }

  // A reference to the deleteRow method which we can use inside addEventListener inside renderRows
  boundDeleteRow = (event) => { this.deleteRow(event, this) }

  // Render rows
  renderRows = (arr, container) => {
    // Just added a reference to the CountriesList instance ("that")
    let el = document.querySelector(container),
        that = this;
    el.innerHTML = "";
    
    arr.forEach((item) => {
        let row = `<tr>
              <td>${item.name}</td>
              <td class="text-right">${item.code}</td>
              <td class="text-right">
                <button data-code="${item.code}" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
                  <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" style="pointer-events:none;"></i>
                </button>
              </td>
           </tr>`;
         el.innerHTML += row;
    });
      
    // add event listener to every row (I used querySelectorAll because sometimes countires show up more than once in your list)
    // added "that" as the second param so I can use it to reference the CountriesList instance
    el.querySelectorAll(`button[data-code]`).forEach((i) => {
      i.addEventListener('click',that.boundDeleteRow);
    },that);
  };

  // Get Items
  getFilteredCountries = async() => {
    const response = await fetch(this.apiURL);
    this.countries = await response.json();
    // If there is a search string, filter results
    this.stringToMatch = this.searchBox.value;
    if (this.stringToMatch.length > 0) {
      this.countries = this.countries.filter((country) => {
        return (
          country.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.stringToMatch.toLowerCase()) ||
          country.code.includes(this.stringToMatch.toUpperCase())
        );
      });
      this.renderRows(this.countries, "#countries_table tbody");
    }
  };

  deleteRow(event, that) {
    let deleteBtns = document.querySelectorAll("#countries_table tr button");
    this.countries = this.countries.filter((item) => item.code != event.target.getAttribute('data-code'));
    this.renderRows(this.countries, "#countries_table tbody");
  };

  hideLoader = async() => {
    let loader = document.querySelector(".loader");
    const action = this.countries.length > 0 ? "add" : "remove";
    loader.classList[action]("d-none");
  };

  init = async() => {
    await this.getFilteredCountries();
    await this.hideLoader();
    this.searchBox.addEventListener("keyup", this.getFilteredCountries);
    this.renderRows(this.countries, "#countries_table tbody");
  };
}

const countriesList = new CountriesList();
countriesList.init();
```

```css
.loader {
  border: 4px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-top: 4px solid #3498db;
  opacity: .85;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="card bg-light shadow-sm my-2">
    <div class="card-header px-3 d-flex">
      <h6 class="text-dark m-0 align-self-center">Countries of the World</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body bg-white position-relative p-0">
      <div class="search mx-2">
        <input class="my-2 form-control" id="searchBox" type="text" placeholder="Search..." value="">
      </div>
      <table class="table mb-0" id="countries_table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th class="text-right">Code</th>
            <th class="text-right">Delete</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div class="loader"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try doing a search (filter) then delete _from the search results_ ad see what the console throws.

Comment: Looks to be working fine now. Probably better for you to make the change in your stylesheet, but it seems to me that the problem was that click events were being swallowed up by the <i></i>tag used for the cross icon in each button.

Comment: If I filter, delete, he "unfilter" (delete the search expression), the deleted country appears again :(

Comment: I'm confused here. You are fetching the same data from your API every single time getFilteredCountries is called (such as when you search) and your deleteRow function just removes a country from the current value of this.countries, so of course a deleted country is back again after you search/filter because you're overwriting this.countries with a complete list of countries from your API. You can store the deleted countries as another property and check against it in getFilteredCountries, but that's outside the scope of your question.

Answer (score 1):

The core issue is: The `this` keyword, in your case, references the `button` element. A primitive example:

```html
<button onclick="console.log(this)">Click me</button>
```

You assume that, because you create the button inside a class, `this` will refer to that class. What you do, however, is simply create a string containing HTML and then set that string as the `innerHTML` of an element in your DOM. What you end up with is, essentially, my snippet from up in my answer: Just a button hanging somewhere in the DOM. And events fired by DOM elements have the element itself set for the `this` keyword.

In order to achieve what you actually want, you'll need some kind of reference to your class instance inside your `onClick` listener. A simple way would be to make your class instance accessible globally as a variable, then call the method on that variable. Here's a boiled-down example:

```js
    class Renderer {
        render() {
            const target = document.querySelector("#app");
            target.innerHTML = `<button onClick="renderer.doSomething()">hi</button>`
        }
        doSomething() {
            console.log("I am doing something...");
        }
    }
    const renderer = new Renderer();
    renderer.render();
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

Obviously, there are a flaws with this sample, but it should show you why the approach you have chosen does not work and what the way forward could be.